# Freeze on BIOS screen after boot-repair puts a certain file as EFI

Tags: boot, uefi

I am trying to create a dual boot of Windows 8 and Ubuntu on an Acer Travelmate P253-M. I successfully install Ubuntu on the hard disk but it doesn't boot. I tried several times with boot-repair, choosing different options but never succeeded. Eventually, I couldn't boot to either Windows or Ubuntu, only through LiveCD. So I went through boot-repair once more which said that I should put a certain file as EFI. I did that, restarted and only Acer logo appeared with nothing else. <kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't work, I can't get in to BIOS any way.

What I have tried:

- Re-seat the RAM
- Trying to boot with other hard drives
- Trying to boot from flash drive
- Trying to boot from CD (and all possible combinations with these three)
- Downloaded BIOS update from the [Acer website](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/drivers), but it only has a version to flash from within Windows (.exe file, but I can't boot to Windows or anything else at all)
- Shorted JCMOS1 jumper for 20 seconds after which the ACER logo disapeared and instead:

  - After I press the power key, a completely black screen appears for about 5 seconds.  After that the backlight on the monitor turns on and the message `Press to enter Setup.` appears on the very bottom. Pressing F2 does nothing.
  - If I hold <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and then power up, system info appears: `Insyde H2O EFI 3.7, Copyright... System BIOS version: v2.13`, processor type etcetera on top and the `Press F2 to enter Setup.` on the bottom.
  - Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> removes the bottom message and scrolls one line up but nothing else.
  - Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> removes the bottom message, scrolls about 4 lines but nothing else.
- I opened the laptop completely, removed the CMOS battery for about an hour, shorted the JCMOS1 pin once again, put it back - nothing.
- I found a way to flash the BIOS (Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, plug power, press power button) if I have the image on a flash drive. However I can't find an image as well.

Comment: Changing ahci to ide in bios setting might help.

Comment: I can't access BIOS setup screen.

Comment: Then you have a hardware problem. You can't even update bios.

Comment: cant you access the BIOS setup screen because it doesn't reach that screen or for an other reason? If it does not even reach that screen it looks like a hardware problem and does have little to do with Ubuntu I am afraid.